# How to find where is the TypeError in my code?

Tags: json, google-chrome-devtools

[image]

I can only provide this picture of the console error.

Comment: Please add the code you're using - [https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask].

Comment: There are a lot of code. It isn't my, it is enterprise application. Anyway, don't know which code to post it :)

Answer (score 2):

The error appears on vendors.min... file which is most likely not your file.

With the screenshot you have I can tell what the error is (Circular JSON...) but there is no way I can tell you where in your code does it happen without more info about your code.

You seem to be passing a JavaScript Object with a Circular reference to your library, which is trying to stringify it (convert into a JSON string) and this errors because objects with a circular references aren't allowed.

For comparison, a concrete example of a circular object would be:

```
const parent = {};
const child1 = { myParent: parent};
const child2 = { myParent: parent};
parent.children = [child1, child2];
```

And at some point you are passing this parent with children with circular reference to the library and that produces the error.

Solution: avoid passing circular references to that library. If you need those references on other parts of your code, consider building a new object without those circular references before handling it to the library function.

PS: Please do consider giving more information next time, the image of the error doesn't help us help you.

Comment: Thank you @corlaez. Don't know which code to send :)

Comment: Got it. As I said try to locate the circular reference. If this is a new error and you are using git then you can use git log to see what parts of the code were recently changed